# Get the key that is mapped to a button in Unity

Tags: input, unity-game-engine

I would like to print out the key that is mapped to a button in Unity.

Imagine something like a tutorial-level ingame, in which the key bindings are explained in this way: "Press [keyMappedTo("Jump")] to jump".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet but something similar should work - once I'll get home I will check it myself too.

```
public string jButton = "Jump" ;
public KeyCode kc ;

void Awake()
{
  kc = (KeyCode)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), jButton) ;
}
```

That should return the keycode assigned for the Jump button keyidentifier.

Comment: I wrote this `KeyCode fire1Button;
fire1Button = (KeyCode)System.Enum.Parse (typeof(KeyCode), "Fire1");` and `fire1Button.ToString()` returns `None`. Plus I get this error `ArgumentException: The requested value 'Fire1' was not found.
System.Enum.Parse (System.Type enumType, System.String value, Boolean ignoreCase)`.

Comment: I don't see how this would work. "Jump" is not in the KeyCode enum.